# could not find function "ga_clientid_activity" in GoogleAnalyticsR

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What has happend to the following function in googleanalyticsR?

```
could not find function "ga_clientid_activity"
```

Comment: Did you run `library(googleAnalyticsR)` to load the package before trying to use the function? What version of the package do you have installed?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to install here: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/user-activity.html ?

Comment: googleAuthR_1.0.0.9000 googleAnalyticsR_0.6.0

Comment: This function needed the dev version until v0.7.0 was released on CRAN last week, so you should be able to use this function now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest version of `googleAnalyticsR` version > 0.7.0